# How can I add text to speech in tensorflow lite object detection android based application?

Tags: android, text-to-speech, tensorflow-lite, object-detection-api

I am building an app that will helps the blind peoples to detect hurdles in their way. For this purpose, i need the application to speak that the object name (i.e Chair,Table) whenever any object is detected.

Comment: Did you find the solution ?

Answer (score 0):

I personally never worked with TensorFlow before, but, if it is something similar like the object detection API from firebase ML Kit, I would do the following.

You could try getting the labels of the object in front of the camera and then using the TTS API of Android to read the string out loud.

I don't know if your app is Android or iOS. I've used TTS before on Android.

Here is the documentation:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/tts/TextToSpeech

And, here is a demo app I built using TTS. it reads whatever you type inban EditText.

https://github.com/AlfredoBejarano/Android-Kotlin-Demos/tree/master/TextToSpeechDemo

Answer (score 0):

The goal to achieve is related to two machine learning tasks: (1) Object detection, and filter objects you are interested in (like hurdles); (2) Text-To-Speech (TTS) - speak the name of that object. You need to combine them in a pipeline.

For the first task, sometimes API can do for many cases, but may not recognize all objects you are interested in. It depends on how many classes of objects that the API can provide. The other factor is that Internet latency of calling an API may be limited, assuming that your app needs to do real-time detection.

Considering above, you may want to train your own mobile detection model and deploy it on Android. There is an TensorFlow Lite object detection example in Android: https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/models/object_detection/overview. It runs purely on-device (no Internet connection is needed), so you may download and try. This blog introduces how to train a custom model: https://medium.com/tensorflow/training-and-serving-a-realtime-mobile-object-detector-in-30-minutes-with-cloud-tpus-b78971cf1193.

For the second task, TTS is relatively mature, so usually it is not necessary to train your own model. Just as pointed by another reply, you can use TTS in Android SDK: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/tts/TextToSpeech. It can also runs offline.

Comment: First task is done already. Actually I got stuck in second task.Do you have any TTS code which works in tensorflowlite?